# Error uploading file to OneDrive through CodeIgniter

Tags: php, azure, onedrive

I have created a web application using CodeIgniter that allows the user to select a file and upload it directly to OneDrive. However, when attempting to upload a file, I receive the error "Error: Unable to open file stream for the given path." I have tried to resolve this issue, but without success. Can anyone provide assistance or guidance on how to fix this error? Thank you

i tried many permissions and all stuffs related to this but no results

Comment: Not seeing any php code. When you receive the error, receiving it from where? Provide more details. And see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can [edit] your question. As you're new please also take the [tour] to learn about how Stackoverflow works. Thanks,.